# AngularJS: Display formatted model value in input when not focussed

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Say I have an input like:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="myVariable">
```

With a value of 600.23 currently. The value of $scope.myVariable should always be 600.23 (unless the user changes the value) I want the input to display $600.23 when the input doesn't have focus, but when the use gives the input focus, I want it to switch to the unformatted ng-model value of 600.23 for the user to edit. Once the user finishes editing and takes away focus, I want the displayed value to once again be currency-formatted. Basically similar to how formatted cells in spreadsheet applications work. For the sake of keeping the question simple, disregard the need for input validation.

This can be accomplished fairly easily with jQuery, but is it possible to do it with pure AngularJS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I created that depends on jQuery (and worse, eval!):

```
angular.module('app', [])
.directive('displayFormat', function () {
    return function (scope, element, attr) {
        $(element).focus(function () {
            $(this).val(eval('scope.' + $(this).attr('ng-model')));
        });
        $(element).blur(function () {
            var modelValue = parseFloat(eval('scope.' + $(this).attr('ng-model')));
            if (attr["displayFormat"] == 'currency') $(this).val('$' + modelValue.numberFormat(2));
            if (attr["displayFormat"] == 'percentage') $(this).val((modelValue * 100) + '%');
        });
    };
});

Number.prototype.numberFormat = function (decimals, dec_point, thousands_sep) {
    dec_point = typeof dec_point !== 'undefined' ? dec_point : '.';
    thousands_sep = typeof thousands_sep !== 'undefined' ? thousands_sep : ',';

    var parts = this.toFixed(decimals).toString().split('.');
    parts[0] = parts[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, thousands_sep);

    return parts.join(dec_point);
}
```

Then in the controller:

```
$scope.$watch(function () {
    $('input').not(':focus').blur();
});
```

And then the input field:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="myVariable" display-format="currency">
```

(In my actual application, I'm going to implement other options for display-format besides currency)

I'd really like to have a non-jQuery solution though.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [ngBlur](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angBlur) ang [ngFocus](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angFocus) to switch values. Create function which will add $ and trigger it on ngBlur and another to remove it.

Comment: I saw these earlier while researching the issue, but it's not clear how I can use them to alter the displayed value while leaving the value of myVariable unchanged.

Comment: No you can`t you have to check if there is $ when processing model